# htaccess Domain Simulation

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a server that hosts stuff automatically from /var/www. I copied a directory like domain.com inside /var/www. I then added domain.com into my /etc/hosts for 127.0.0.1 (localhost/loopback). What's the .htaccess trick with Apache so that I can hit my site with: http://domain.com/ and it automatically knows to look in /var/www/domain.com/ (without redirection of the URL)?

Answer (score 2):

You need a virtual host like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/
  ServerName domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

More information on the Apache documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin mail@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs/domain.com/
    ServerName *.domain.com
    ErrorLog logs/domain-error_log
    CustomLog logs/domain-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

this will look for anything comming in on *:80 and if it's domain.com its DocRoot becomes /var/www/htdocs/domain.com